# Read data from Excel for Cucumber feature

Tags: javascript, node.js, gherkin

Is there any way to make Cucumber Feature read the data from excel instead of having it in examples? I am asking for Node JS(javascript) not for Java.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify something in Gherkin that will read an Excel file. You will have to implement the reading in the steps you define in Javascript.

If you read data from an Excel file, then ask yourself why you need Cucumber. The purpose of using Cucumber is to create scenarios that can be read by business representatives as well as testers and developers. Hiding the details in an Excel file will probably make the examples specified in Gherkin hard to understand.

Comment: Hi Thomos, Thanks for your inputs. But here in my project i have to define the test data in examples section of Feature file. those test data are given by client in excel. its hard for me to copy the data from excel and paste in feature file each and every time i run the feature file.

Comment: Read the Excel document from a Jaca class the. But consider not to add cucumber to the mix. Cucumber is not meant to be used like that so you will save yourself time and effort not to use it in that scenario.